# In iPhone12 mini, status bar height is 44, but why tableView's frame.y = 50?

Tags: ios, swift

I create a tableView, and make it's constraint to fill safeArea:

```
    let safeArea=view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive=true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive=true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive=true
```

I print tableView.frame in viewDidAppear, and I found tableView's frame.y is 50, not 44? Why?

Comment: Try to print in view didLayout method

Comment: printed in viewDidLoad is 0

Comment: not viewDidLoad. viewDidLayout